# Calculator Snippet CC

Tags: javascript, css, html5, calculator, community-challenge

[The April 2015 Community Challenge](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5176/31503) requires building a calculator.

> #### Implement a *simple* calculator
>
> Where the definition of "simple" is whatever you make it - only
>   supports basic arithmetic operators? Fine. It supports scientific
>   notation, exponents and trigonometry? Fine! Takes input from the
>   console? Fine! Toggle between binary, hex, octal and decimal
>   notations? Fine!
>
> The common denominator here, is that you need:
>
> - A way to take user input
> - A way to parse/validate user input
> - A way to perform the operations in the input
> - A way to output the result(s)
>
> Everything else you want to put in, is up to you and the time you can
>   devote to this small project in the limited number of days we have
>   until April is over - be creative!

I am specifically looking for insights on the way I have integrated with the keypressed concept, the way that the system can be extended by adding binary or unary operators, and for any mathematical oversights I currently may have.

I am learning Javascript, CSS, and d3 and I am somewhat sure I am missing basic practices that I should have too. If you see anything that's contrary to industry best practices, please point those out too.

> ***Note:*** I found that the snippet does odd things with key-presses occasionally: here is the standalone 'original' version that I
>   'hacked' to make in to a snippet: [**standalone
>   calc.html**](http://git.tuis.net/ubench/calc.html). I find the
>   experience of the standalone version is better.

```js
var calc = {
    stack: {
        values: new Array(1024),
        size: 0,
        decimal: 0
    },
    
    display: {
        value: 0.0,
        integral: true
    },
    
    layout: [
        {
            compact: false,
            buttons: ["seven", "eight", "nine", "root", "clear"]
        },
        {
            compact: false,
            buttons: ["four", "five", "six", "times", "divide"]
        },
        {
            compact: false,
            buttons: ["one", "two", "three", "plus", "minus"]
        },
        {
            compact: false,
            buttons: ["zero", "point", "plusminus", "exp", "equals"]
        },


    ],

    keys: {},

    buttons: {
        zero: {
            action: function() {return digit(0);},
            label: "0",
            key: [48]
        },
        one: {
            action: function() {return digit(1);},
            label: "1",
            key: [49]
        },
        two: {
            action: function() {return digit(2);},
            label: "2",
            key: [50]
        },
        three: {
            action: function() {return digit(3);},
            label: "3",
            key: [51]
        },
        four: {
            action: function() {return digit(4);},
            label: "4",
            key: [52]
        },
        five: {
            action: function() {return digit(5);},
            label: "5",
            key: [53]
        },
        six: {
            action: function() {return digit(6);},
            label: "6",
            key: [54]
        },
        seven: {
            action: function() {return digit(7);},
            label: "7",
            key: [55]
        },
        eight: {
            action: function() {return digit(8);},
            label: "8",
            key: [56]
        },
        nine: {
            action: function() {return digit(9);},
            label: "9",
            key: [57]
        },


        point: {
            action: function() {
                if (calc.stack.decimal === 0) {
                    calc.stack.decimal = 1;
                }
                return peek();
            },
            label: ".",
            key: [46]
        },

        root: {
            action: function() {
                return unaryOp(function(val) {
                    return Math.sqrt(val);
                });
            },
            label: "r\u221A",
            color: "black",
            key: [114]
        },

        plusminus: {
            action: function() {
                return unaryOp(function(val) {
                    return -val;
                });
            },
            label: "~\u00B1",
            key: [126]
        },

        plus: {
            action: function() {
                return binaryOp(calc.buttons.plus);
            },
            operate: function(left, right) {
                return left + right;
            },
            label: "+",
            color: "black",
            key: [43]
        },
        minus: {
            action: function() {
                return binaryOp(calc.buttons.minus);
            },
            operate: function(left, right) {
                return left - right;
            },
            label: "-",
            color: "black",
            key: [45]
        },
        times: {
            action: function() {
                return binaryOp(calc.buttons.times);
            },
            operate: function(left, right) {
                return left * right;
            },
            label: "*",
            color: "black",
            key: [42,120]
        },
        divide: {
            action: function() {
                return binaryOp(calc.buttons.divide);
            },
            operate: function(left, right) {
                return left / right;
            },
            label: "/\u00F7",
            color: "black",
            key: [47]
        },
        exp: {
            action: function() {
                return binaryOp(calc.buttons.exp);
            },
            operate: function(left, right) {
                return Math.pow(left , right);
            },
            label: "EXP^",
            color: "black",
            key: [94]
        },
        equals: {
            action: function() {resolve();},
            label: "=",
            color: "black",
            key: [61,13]
        },
        clear: {
            action: function() {reset();},
            label: "del",
            color: "orange",
            key: [32, 127]
        }
    }
    
};

function peek() {
    if (calc.stack.size == 0) {
        throw "Empty stack peek()";
    }
    return calc.stack.values[calc.stack.size - 1];
}

function pop() {
    if (calc.stack.size == 0) {
        throw "Empty stack pop()";
    }
    calc.stack.size--;
    var val = calc.stack.values[calc.stack.size];
    calc.stack.values[calc.stack.size] = null;
    return val;
}

function push(val) {
    calc.stack.values[calc.stack.size++] = val;
    return val;
}

function cleared() {
    return calc.stack.size == 0;
}

function reset() {
    while(calc.stack.size != 0) {
        pop();
    }
    push(0);
    calc.stack.decimal = 0;
}


function updateDisplay() {
    var disp = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < calc.stack.size; i++) {
        if (typeof calc.stack.values[i] == "number") {
            disp += " " + calc.stack.values[i];
        } else {
            disp += " " + calc.stack.values[i].label;
        }
    }
    d3.select("#display")
      .attr("value", "" + disp);
}

function resolve() {
    var val = pop();
    while (!cleared()) {
        var op = pop();
        var left = pop();
        var eq = op.operate(left,val);
        console.log("Compute: " + left + " " + op.label + " " + val + " -> " + eq);
        val = eq;
    }
    push(val);
    calc.stack.decimal = 0;
}

function unaryOp(fn) {
    // unary expects a value at stack-top.
    if ("number" != typeof peek()) {
        console.log("Evict " + pop());
    }
    push(fn(pop()));
}

function binaryOp(fn) {
    resolve();
    push(fn);
    push(0);
}

function digit(val) {
    if (calc.stack.decimal === 0) {
        return push(pop() * 10 + val);
    }
    calc.stack.decimal /= 10.0;
    var current = pop();
    var n = calc.stack.decimal * val;
    var tp = n + current;
    //console.log("Current " + current + " decimal " + calc.stack.decimal + "... new " + n + " to push " + tp);
    return push(tp);
}

function pressButton(name) {
    var detail = calc.buttons[name];
    //console.log("Button pressed: " + name);
    detail.action();
    d3.select("#" + name)
        .style("background-color", "red")
        .transition()
        .style("background-color", detail.color);
    updateDisplay();
}

function keyHook(kevent) {
    var k = kevent.keyCode || kevent.which;
    if (calc.keys[k]) {
        console.log("Keypress code " + kevent.keyCode + " which: " + kevent.which + " linked to " + calc.keys[k]);
        pressButton(calc.keys[k]);
        return;
    }
    console.log("Unrecognized Keypress " + k);
}

function setup() {
    
    var buttons = d3.select("#buttons");
    
    calc.layout.forEach(function(row) {
        row.buttons.forEach(function(bid){
            var b = calc.buttons[bid];
            b.id = bid;
            b.color = b.color || "darkslategray";
            var title = "Key:";
            b.key.forEach(function(k){
                var kname = String.fromCharCode(k);
                title = title + " '" + kname + "'";
                calc.keys[k] = bid;
            });
            buttons.append("input")
                .classed("button",true)
                .style("background-color", b.color)
                .attr("title", title)
                .attr("type", "button")
                .attr("id", bid)
                .attr("value", b.label)
                .attr("onclick", "pressButton(this.id);");
        });
        buttons.append("br");
    });
    window.onkeypress=keyHook;
    reset();
    updateDisplay();
}

setup();
```

```css
    #display {
        text-align: right;
        font: bold 50px monospace;
        background-color: darkgray;
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .button {
        font: bold 35px monospace;
        color: white;
        margin: 10px;
        width: 3em;
    }

    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        margin: 0 auto
    }

    table.main {
      background-color: lightgray;
      border: 2px solid darkgray;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

      <table class="main">
        <caption>CodeReview Calculator</caption> 
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input id="display" value="0" size="15" readonly="true" >
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div id="buttons"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        
      </table>
```

Comment: Wow, that's pretty cool!

Comment: [I wrote one too](http://jsfiddle.net/calraith/n5amL6t0/).  Yours does more than mine, though.  Feel free to swipe ideas -- CSS, drag and drop, fonts, whatever.  You've got a bug, though.  Negative results don't appear negative.  Try doing `5 - 10`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Beyond not having the basic framework for the HTML, you have one error according to the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input):

```
<input id="display" value="0" size="15" readonly="true" >
```

`readonly="true"` is not valid, the correct attribute is `readonly="readonly"`

There is a pretty bad UI problem here.  When you click the buttons as follows `9 - 3 = 2`, the calculator reads `62`, whereas it should reset and only read `2` because you clicked the `=` button.

---

Beyond this, your calculator does not follow the order of operations.  Probably the simplest way to handle this would be to only update the calculation when the `+`, `-`, and `=` buttons are pressed (like the Windows calculator does), parsing and calculating everything else from the stack.

Comment: I've always read that the correct way to specify `readonly` is to simply include `readonly` without a value in the element.

Comment: That probably works in some browsers, but not necessarily in all. The same applies for `selected` on an `option` element in a `select`. Normally, you'd just do `selected`, but sometimes, you need to do `selected="selected"`. Also `disabled`.

Answer (score 4):

I see a lot of repeated code, especially in the construction of the buttons, double especially for the digit buttons. It seems that they should be constructible by a `for` loop and an appropriate data structure.